# Laravel hasOne how to save ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel but i really love it already.
Right now I play a little bit with Eloquent and a question came up:

I Have Cusomers with two addresses (BillingAdress and DeliveryAddress)

Cusomers-Fields: ID, Firstname, Lastname, BillingAddress, DeliveryAddress
Addresses-Fields: ID, Address, Zip, City, Country

Now I want to create the customer and after I created him I want to assign him his addresses.

**Customer Model:**

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function deliveryAddress() {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Address");
    }

    public function billingAddress() {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Address");
    }
}
```

**Address Model:**

```
 class Address extends Model
    {
        public function customer() {
            return $this->belongsTo("App\Customer");
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
$c = new Customer;
$c->Firstname = "John";
$c->Lastname = "Doe";
$c->save();

$billingAddress = new Address;
$billingAddress->address = "Exampleroad 3";
$billingAddress->zip = 11111;
$billingAddress->city = "Examplecity";

$deliveryAddress = new Address;
$deliveryAddress->address = "Doestreed 21";
$deliveryAddress->zip = "44444";
$deliveryAddress->city = "Doedown";

$c->billingAddress()->save($billingAddress);
$c->deliveryAddress()->save($deliveryAddress);
```

But right now the cusomer_id in the addresses table gets saved but deliveryAddress and billingAddress in the cusomer table is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the foreign and local key so Laravel knows what fields you are referring to for ids.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function deliveryAddress() {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Address", "id", "deliveryAddress");
    }

    public function billingAddress() {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Address", "id", "billingAddress");
    }
}
```

The full documentation on how to use these can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: ok i think i was because the function named exactly like the column?? now i changed the functio name but the fields are still null in the database